# How to set http url in "$ref" as URL Reference dynamically & environment specific in swagger yaml file while referring to the external components?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen, swagger-editor

How to set http url in "$ref" as URL Reference dynamically & environment specific in swagger yaml file while referring to the external components?

```
 Address:
      $ref: 'https://HOST:PORT/api/model/v1/components.yaml#/components/schemas/Address'
```

In above url, I want to pick HOST:PORT for each environment either from a properties file or some external source dynamically.

Referred swagger doc:
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/

Answer (score 0):

When you document an API, it is common to have some features which you use across several of API resources. In that case, you can create a snippet for such elements in order to use them multiple times when you need it. With OpenAPI 3.0, you can reference a definition hosted on any location. It can be the same server, or another one – for example, GitHub, SwaggerHub, and so on. To reference a definition, use the $ref keyword:
$ref: 'reference to definition'

try it here.
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/

Comment: This is same docs which i've already referred but my ask was a bit different, Could you please have a look on my question again? :)